# How to get a slice of references from a vector in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

Somewhere in the API I use I have a function which takes `&[&A]` as argument but I only have a vector of `A` objects. When I try to use this function with
[following syntax](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c85970c4a6ddea2442e2db95da1df3e6&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
pub struct A(pub u64);

fn test(a: &[&A]){}

fn main() {
   let v = vec![A(1), A(2), A(3)];
   let a = &v[..];
   test(a);
}
```

I have a error:

```
<anon>:12:9: 12:10 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&[&A]`,
    found `&[A]`
(expected &-ptr,
    found struct `A`) [E0308]
```

I have made some attempts but without any success:

```
let a = &v[&..]
```

and

```
let a = &v[&A]
```

How can I make `&[&A]` from `Vec<A>`?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. These types are not compatible with each other.

Comment: Well, I am interesting then - how do functions of the API I use supposed to run if they have this kind of arguments?

Comment: What you could do if this is really what the API needs is `test(&v.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>());`. But this allocates a new vector. If you are the author of the API, consider changing it: `[&T]` is a weird type to work with since you need different owners for the slice and the objects in it. `&[T]` already has a pass-by-reference semantic of the inner objects.

Comment: @mcarton Thanks, I'll make a PR then and contant the maintainer. Don't know what to do with this question. Maybe you will answer with this information?

Comment: if changing `test` is an option, it can be defined as `fn test<T: std::borrow::Borrow<A>>(a: &[T]){}`, this will accept both `&[&A] and &[A]. This will be backward compatible too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. These types are not compatible with each other.

What you could do if this is really what the API needs is

```
test(&v.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>());
```

But this allocates a new vector. If you are the author of the API, consider changing it: `&[&T]` is a weird type to work with since you need different owners for the slice and the objects in it. `&[T]` already has a pass-by-reference semantic of the inner objects.

Comment: @Shepmaster do you have any concrete example where this would be useful? The only use of `&[&T]` I can think of would be `&[&'static str]`.

Comment: One I can think of is a reference to a trait object: `&[&Display]`. Depending on the API, they may need to maintain backwards compatibility too.