# What's the best way to convert from a Vec to a slice of references?

Tags: rust

So let's say I have some struct instances in a Vec:

```
let records: Vec<Foo> = ...;
```

And I need to use them with a function which takes a slice of references as an argument:

```
fn my_func(arg: &[&Foo]) { ... }
```

How can I get a slice of references out of the Vec?  I see there is an `as_slice` method, but this would give me a slice of `Foo`, not a slice of `&Foo`.

Comment: Simplest is `&records.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a slice of references from a vector in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797242/how-to-get-a-slice-of-references-from-a-vector-in-rust)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the [`iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/) method on a vector `Vec<T>` creates and returns an iterator over `&T`. Then you can create a `Vec<&T>` and pass a reference to it to `my_func()`. Passing `&Vec<&T>` to a function that expects `&[&T]` is possible via [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods).

Here is an example where I've used `u64` instead of `Foo`, for the sake of simplicity:

```
fn my_func(arg: &[&u64]) {
    println!("arg = {arg:?}")    
}

fn main() {
    let records: Vec<u64> = vec![77, 33];
    let a: Vec<&u64> = records.iter().collect();
    my_func(&a);
}
```

Also note that this line:

```
let a: Vec<&u64> = records.iter().collect();
```

Could be replaced with any of these:

```
let a: Vec<_> = records.iter().collect();
let a = records.iter().collect::<Vec<&u64>>();
let a = records.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Comment: Cool, it works, thank you!  How does the Vec<&T> get converted to a slice?  Is this implicit?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain just that. It's possible with something called **deref coercion**.